# Menu list item and top border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add top border to a menu list item which will shows on hover action, but somehow it makes first menu item (drop down) to to "jump" when top bar is added.

CSS for that part looks like:

```
header nav ul.sub-menu li:hover {
    border-top:4px solid; 
}
```

and menu HTML

```
<div class="main-menu">
  <nav>
    <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
      <ul class="menu" id="menu-header-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-487" id="menu-item-487"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-482 has-menu level1" id="menu-item-482"><a href="#our-company/">Our Company</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <div class="menu_arrow"></div>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-483" id="menu-item-483"><a href="#our-team/">Our Team</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-544" id="menu-item-544"><a href="#contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-431 has-menu level1" id="menu-item-431"><a href="#our-approach/">Investment Approach</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <div class="menu_arrow"></div>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-633" id="menu-item-633"><a href="#our-process/">Our Process</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-407" id="menu-item-407"><a href="#portfolio/">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-653" id="menu-item-653"><a href="#news-insights/">News &amp; Insights</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- .menu --> 
  </nav>
</div>
```

Any clue?

Comment: Are you missing the colour from the border?

Comment: `<div>` is not a valid child of `<ul>`; Also IIRC a border is added to the margin of an element, so it will move it down if there is no space for it to grow.

Comment: @dotty: “Missing” border-color will use the value of `color` automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use a transparent border as a placeholder, just because margin may interact with neighboring margins.

```
li {border-top:4px solid transparent;}
li:hover {border-top:4px solid black;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try CSS like this:

```
nav ul.sub-menu li {
    margin-top: 4px;
}

nav ul.sub-menu li:hover {
    margin-top: 0;
    border-top:4px solid; 
}
```

This adds a margin placeholder for your border, so when your border appears it takes the place of the margin and doesn't give the moving effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/7SGNd/1/

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you can use `box-sizing: border-box;` if you want to maintain a fixed height. You'd have to use a clear border or maybe padding instead of a margin in the non-hover state, however.

Comment: Thanks, Cezary. Might be worth putting as another answer :)

Comment: Well, have tried both but still getting that strange effect on a first drop down menu. Staging site here: http://www.interactstaging.us/rockspringcapital/

Comment: @JackTheKnife Seems like I misunderstood the issue. Not sure what strange effect you're talking about.

Comment: @Shredder is gone because marked answer had solved my problem